# GET page through socket python3

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I'm trying to get a page via a socket proxy in python 3. I first make a connection to a proxy listed on https://sslproxies.org and then send the `GET` request :

```
GET https://icanhazip.com HTTP/1.1\r\n
```

But it gives an error, saying :

> HTTP Bad Request 400 (the data is invalid)

So I tried avoiding the Host parameter by using `HTTP/1.0`, but that also did not work.

What request does work?

**Full code :**

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = "xx.xx.xx.xx"
port = 80
s.connect((host, port))
s.sendall("GET https://icanhazip.com HTTP/1.0\r\n".encode("utf-8"))

res = s.recv(10000)
while len(res) > 0:
    print(res)
    res = s.recv(10000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is correct: you are sending a bad request. Unfortunately there are many things wrong with your request which means there is no easy single fix. Definitely wrong are:

- There is no end-of-header delimiter (i.e. empty line `\r\n`).
- There is no `Host` header, which is required with HTTP/1.1 (as you use in your example how a request looks like) and is not required by the standard but still required by most servers with HTTP/1.0 (as you use in your actual code).
- You cannot just put a `https://` url in the request and assume that it will be magically do https. Instead you need to connect to the server, to a SSL handshake and then send a proper HTTP request which contains only the path but not the full URL. When connecting to a proxy (as you seem to attempt) you even need to add some CONNECT request and read its response before you upgrade the socket to SSL.
- You assume that you can use port 80 to for HTTPS, but its port 443 by default, but when connecting to a proxy you actually use the same port for HTTP and HTTP although it is usually something like 8000, 8080 or similar.
- And maybe more.

In short: use a HTTP library. If you don't want to use one study the HTTP standard and don't just look at examples (if you even did that so far).

Comment: Thanks for the request breakdown. I'll look even further into the HTTP request standard since libraries seem to disagree with my computer.
Could you please clarify the `CONNECT` request or SSL handshake? I'm stuck on those topics. Any help appreciated, accepted your answer.

Comment: @Hasyar: I have no idea what I should clarify since I have no idea on what you know already and where you are stuck. And if libraries seem to disagree with your computer (which I interpret as you fail to install these) it might be faster to fix this issue compared to learning everything you need in order to write a replacement for these libraries yourself.

Comment: Got it, and yes the pip installation seems to be bugged. I'll fix that then. Thanks.